# NSDate date string conversion to java.util.date

Tags: java, ios, grails

I have a grails server that receives a JSON request having an NSDate. The Date I receive is of the following format:

2012-01-23 04:47:27 +0000

I need to convert this to a JAVA data format to be able to store. I am doing the following for conversion:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(request.JSON.StartDate);
```

The formatted date comes out as: Sun Jan 22 20:47:27 PST 2012

When I try to do a save(), I get the following error:

> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>
> Field error in object 'com.test.date' on field 'StartDate': rejected
>   value [Sun Jan 22 20:47:27 PST 2012]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.com.test.date.eventStartDate,typeMismatch.StartDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [com.test.date.StartDate,StartDate]; arguments []; default
>   message [StartDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property
>   value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for
>   property 'StartDate'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property
>   'StartDate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this and what do I need to look into?

EDIT:

I actually get the error even when I do the following:

```
object.date = new Date()
object.save()
```

This is not due to the formatting!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code compiles as shown, but in any case it looks like you are formatting a date, then immediately storing (and eventually trying to save) its String representation. Just remove the extra unnecessary conversion to String:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = formatter.parse(request.JSON.StartDate);
```

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make the post simpler and made a mistake. I was actually putting the result of the formatter into a Date. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

UnBelievable!!!! I struggled two days with this issue and it turns out that the Grails domain class property name that I was using is the issue. I was using "eventStartDate" earlier and when I changed it to "DOB" it started working perfectly.

I am very new to Grails and not very sure about the naming restrictions but I learnt a good lesson not to ignore the allowable naming ;)